# jConfirm form submit returns incorrect value to php

Tags: php, jquery

hi im using jConfirm to return form submission to php

my html looks like this:

```
<form id="formdelete" name="formdelete" method="post" action="/home.php">
<input type="hidden" name="remove_user" id="remove_user" value="3">
<input type="submit" value="" border="0" name="image" src="" id="removeuser" class="ui-removes" onclick="DeleteUser();return false;">
</form>

<form id="formdelete" name="formdelete" method="post" action="/home.php">
<input type="hidden" name="remove_user" id="remove_user" value="4">
<input type="submit" value="" border="0" name="image" src="" id="removeuser" class="ui-removes" onclick="DeleteUser();return false;">
</form>

<form id="formdelete" name="formdelete" method="post" action="/home.php">
<input type="hidden" name="remove_user" id="remove_user" value="5">
<input type="submit" value="" border="0" name="image" src="" id="removeuser" class="ui-removes" onclick="DeleteUser();return false;">
</form>
```

my javascript looks like this:

```
function DeleteUser(){
  jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Box', function(r) {
    if(r){
      $("#formdelete").submit();
      return true;
    }
    else
      return false;
  });
}
```

but the value returned to PHP is always wrong. it returns 5 even tho i've clicked on value 4

it works fine if i use a normal javascript such as the following:

```
function DeleteUser(){
      result = confirm('Delete?');
  if(!result)
    return false;

  submit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `id`'s should be unique... so change that...

with your current code you can still get the desired output like this,
lets try a bit change..

```
<input type="submit" value="" border="0" name="image" src="" id="removeuser" class="ui-removes" onclick="DeleteUser();return false;">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" value="" border="0" name="image" src="" id="removeuser" class="ui-removes" onclick="return DeleteUser();">
```

then

```
function DeleteUser(){
  jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Box', function(r) {
    if(r){
      $("#formdelete").submit();
      return true;
    }
    else
      return false;
  });
}
```

to

```
function DeleteUser(){
  jConfirm('Can you confirm this?', 'Confirmation Box', function(r) {   return r; });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The id "formdelete" is ambiguous. an ID attribute can only appear once in a document.

Comment: oh my bad. hey ben, so in fact i can just use one <form> right??